# PDI Job Sees Inconsistent JCR Content

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I've written a Kettle job that moves files from Pentaho 5.3 (SP201505) JCR folders to Windows file-system folders (on the same server; Server 2008 R2 Enterprise). The "move" part of the job uses the **Copy Files** step with the **Remove source files** option selected.

Initially the job runs as expected, moving all files from the source JCR folders to the destination file-system folders.

Before this job runs again Pentaho users have placed new files into the source JCR folders. However, when I next run this job it no longer sees any files in the source JCR folders, even though I can browse them from within the PUC.

I'm running the job from within Spoon (while coding and testing). It is using the VFS protocol **jcr-solution** to access files within JCR folders.

Does this job need to do some kind of repository refresh each time it runs in order to see changes to the JCR folders, and if so, how would this been done within the job?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently multiple instances of the JCR file system are not dynamically coherent.

I reverse-engineered plugin **Pentaho Repository Synchronizer** and figured out how to refresh my local instance of the JCR. The refresh can be accomplished via the following code segment in PDI transformation step **User Defined Java Class**. This code expects the file system root URI to be in an input field named **RootURI**:

```
import org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject;
import org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    try
    {
        // Get a row from the input hop.
        Object[] r=getRow();

        // Are we are done?
        if (r==null) 
        {
            // Yes.
            setOutputDone();
            return false;
        }

        // No, pick up the file system root URI from a field named RootURI.
        // RootURI example: "jcr-solution:http://admin:password@localhost:8080/pentaho!/"
        String fileName=get(Fields.In,"RootURI").getString(r);

        // Get the file system object and close it.
        FileObject jcrObject=KettleVFS.getFileObject(fileName);
        if ((jcrObject!=null)&&(jcrObject.exists()))
        {
            KettleVFS.getInstance().getFileSystemManager().closeFileSystem(jcrObject.getFileSystem());
            KettleVFS.getInstance().getFileSystemManager().getFilesCache().close();
            //System.out.println("*** JCR Refreshed ***");
        }

        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new KettleException(e);
    }
}
```

The above solution seems to have solved my problem.